# How to validate html textbox not to allow leading and trailing whitespaces

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My html is:

```
 <input type="text" name="username">
```

If we write any validation also ,i need the function related stuff to happen in typescript but not java script.

Comment: You mean :`<input required pattern=".*\S+.*" title="This field is required">`

Comment: Check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236992/how-to-validate-white-spaces-empty-spaces-angular-2

Comment: Yeah i have to apply pattern.Correct.But what if I have to apply to say many text fields that too in different page .Is there a way to apply a pattern to all the text fields once at a time?

Comment: not possible with HTML but you can go with custom validator in typescript

Comment: Yes I wanted those validators written in typescript.Can you please give me a code example in typescript?

Comment: The link which i share above has the solution what you are expecting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate white spaces/empty spaces? \[Angular 2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236992/how-to-validate-white-spaces-empty-spaces-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use Regex in whatever implementation you need to filter for leading/trailing whitespace. If you want simple validation, try the HTML5 `pattern` attribute.

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bJCJBv/2