# How to extend Validator.required?

Tags: forms, angular, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I've don't want Validators.required to consider just whitespace as fulfilling its requirement.

Rather than adding an extra validator to my formControl, I'd like to extend Angular's Validators.required. Can someone point me to any info on how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate white spaces/empty spaces? \[Angular 2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236992/how-to-validate-white-spaces-empty-spaces-angular-2)

Comment: Why not use the built in `Validators.pattern`?