# Directive to disable Cut, Copy and Paste function for textbox using Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Angular2 to restrict the copy and paste in textbox. But how do i write a custom directive, so that it will be easy to apply for all the text fields.

Below is the working code to restrict the copy and paste functionality.

```
<ion-input formControlName="confirmpass" type="tel" (cut)="$event.preventDefault()" (copy)="$event.preventDefault()" (paste)="$event.preventDefault()"></ion-input>
```

Comment: I found this question by looking for the exact opposite, if there was a way to override this horrible behavior on a site made in Angular... I know this is an old question but if anyone reads this: please do NOT prevent pasting of passwords! see the following discussion about why this is not a good idea: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131106/is-there-any-reason-to-disable-paste-password-on-login

Comment: @ThomasMulder me too, I just shared workarounds to bypass this behavior if the app uses pure JavaScript events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-events-of-a-dom-object/56849582#56849582
But now I used a website that had restrictions on dates with Angular and I was not able to disable it without breaking the app so I would also be interested to know if there is a solution to disable Angular form validation and restriction.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use a [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) in your directive to catch [cut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/cut), [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste) and [copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/copy) events and then use `preventDefault()`. Here's an example

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBlockCopyPaste]'
})
export class BlockCopyPasteDirective {
  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  @HostListener('copy', ['$event']) blockCopy(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  @HostListener('cut', ['$event']) blockCut(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Use directive like so

```
<ion-input appBlockCopyPaste formControlName="confirmpass" type="tel"></ion-input>
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4jcam?file=app%2Fblock-copy-paste.directive.ts)

Comment: KeyboardEvent Deprecated   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: @RajaRamaMohanThavalam - `keyCode` is deprecated, not `KeyboardEvent`

Comment: Not a working solution anymore. KeyboardEvent has been Deprecated

Comment: Thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this

```
<input (paste)="(false)" />
```

Comment: By far the cleanest solution I've seen so far. This should definitely be the approved answer

Comment: Agree with @GM, this should be the ultimate answer

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Renderer` to listen to `cut,copy,paste` events and call `preventDefault()` in your directive something like

```
@Directive({ selector: '[preventCutCopyPaste]' })

export class CopyDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
      var events = 'cut copy paste';
      events.split(' ').forEach(e => 
      renderer.listen(el.nativeElement, e, (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        })
      );

    }
}
```

Then in html

```
<input type="text" preventCutCopyPaste/>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-attribute-fhthzj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Not a working solution. Cut, copy and paste actions are possible even after implementing this code.

Answer (score 1):

this work for me (paste)="(false)" put this code in input field