# How to restrict Special character in material input

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives, angular6, angular-directive

I have a material input control, i have restrict the special character while user enter, but when type some words in any editor and copy and paste the words with special character, which is not working.

I have write the directive for that to prevent special character,but can one provide the better solution  restrict in copy paste.

app.component.html:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput specialIsAlphaNumeric placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[specialIsAlphaNumeric]'
})
export class SpecialCharacterDirective {

    regexStr = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$';
    @Input() isAlphaNumeric: boolean;

    @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
        return new RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key);
    }

}
```

[demo see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cijbqy-biwrck?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cijbqy-biwrck?file=app%2Finput-overview-e[stackblit[image: ][1]]

Steps to reproduce:

type it special character which is not allowed : working fine.
while copy paste wit allows special character

Comment: try `onchange` or `onChange` instead of `keypress`

Comment: @Hussain I have tried OnChange  as well as paste events all gets triggered,but it allow to paste.if your solution , please update here `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cijbqy-biwrck?file=app/specialChracter.directive.ts`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try Like this:

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cijbqy-kksm37)

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[specialIsAlphaNumeric]'
})
export class SpecialCharacterDirective {

  regexStr = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$';
  @Input() isAlphaNumeric: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }


  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    return new RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key);
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.validateFields(event);
  }

  validateFields(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {

      this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
      event.preventDefault();

    }, 100)
  }

}
```

Comment: @MohamedSahir, if you want the original answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384952/directive-to-disable-cut-copy-and-paste-function-for-textbox-using-angular2 its includes cut and copy too.

Comment: @UnluckyAj which is working as expected for input field,when work with multiinput controls , which has splitted the character as 1 tab and empty string as another tab while copy paste this text DDD@# , so it takes DDD as first and @# replace with '' not working as expected. attached a screenshot and create a demo

Comment: @UnluckyAj this solution suffers from a flash in the UI which is fixed in my solution below

Comment: Thanks for StackBlitz!

Comment: It works but it is not allowing space between char and i need the space?

Comment: all space in regex. @MoHalem

Answer (score 3):

The following approach works without using the setTimeout call, which means there is no flashing of special characters in the input control when the [other response by Aashish K Jha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51428994/3121292) is used

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[specialIsAlphaNumeric]'
})

export class SpecialCharacterDirective {

  regexStr = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$';
  @Input() isAlphaNumeric: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }


  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    return new RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key);
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    this.validateFields(event);
  }

  validateFields(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const pasteData = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, pasteData);
  }
}
```

Comment: the absence of the setTimeout means there is no flash when the users pastes their content, a much improved outcome than simply waiting 100ms

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ng Knife](https://github.com/marcelocanales/ng-knife) utility

1. Import NgKnifeModule

   ```
   ... 
   import { NgKnifeModule } from 'ng-knife';
   ...
   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
       AppComponent
     ],
     imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       NgKnifeModule
     ],
     ...
   });
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
2. Using it:

   ```
   <!-- Aphanumeric -->
   <input knifeAlphanumeric type="text">
   ```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest solution out there. Why reinvent the wheel if someone else has already done it!? Thx for this!