# Ionic Cordova App How to Disable Copy & Paste in Ion-Input Field

Tags: ionic-framework

I've tried solution by applying CSS styles to input field but its not working. Can I know is there any other suggested method?

```
.registration-input-box > input {
    --ion-color-success: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;    
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-callout: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-touch-callout: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

```
<ion-input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" class="registration-input-box"></ion-input>
```

Comment: You can listen event and cancel the action if the event is called. I think this thread can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384952/directive-to-disable-cut-copy-and-paste-function-for-textbox-using-angular2/47385485

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and seems like ionic doesn't have a quick option for this, but I found this HTML event attributes that we can add to the  tag so we can prevent the user from copy, paste, drag or drop text in the input field.

- onPaste = "return false"
- onCopy = "return false"
- onCut = "return false"
- onDrag = "return false"
- onDrop = "return false"
- autocomplete = off

```
<ion-input onPaste="return false" 
           onCopy="return false" 
           onCut="return false" 
           onDrag="return false" 
           onDrop="return false" 
           autocomplete=off 
           type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
```